# rn-pdf-reader-js does not display pdf file in offline Mode

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing mobile Application using expo and using expo-file-system to store pdf file in  the mobile device. Now, when i am opening the file using rn-pdf-reader-js, it works smooth using Internet, but in offline mode the package does not work. I have tried other package, none of the pdf packages are working in expo, not even installing. Can anyone help me out yrr.

```
FileLink in Mobile Device : file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540anuj21%252Flms/PPTNotes/11_Ensemble_techniques-3928.pdf
```

```
            <PDFReader
                source={{
                    uri: 'file://' + props.route.params.pdfUri,
                }}
                withPinchZoom={true}
                withScroll={true}

            />
```